# generate a set of strings from a given string

Tags: php, string

Let's assume the following -simplified- string: 'Xyy'.

Starting from this, I would like to exchange all 'y' with all possible combinations of 0 and 1 (also simplified).

Accordingly, the result should be: X00, X01, X10, X11.

Thank you!

Comment: are 0,1 fixed for all such cases

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n

Comment: do not simplify too much your issue

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
function gen() {      
    for($i=0;$i<=1;$i++) { 
        for($j=0;$j<=1;$j++) {    
            yield "X{$i}{$j}";     
        } 
    }
```

}

and invoke it like so:

```
   foreach(gen() as $val) {                     
       echo $val . " ";    
   }
```